# How to get the value from my pointer address in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a pointer and storing this in a native hash map, but how do I convert this back to my struct when getting the value back?

I create it like this:

```
T* p = &myStruct;
hashMap.Add(myStruct, (int)p); //<MyStruct,int>
```

Now reading it back I am trying to do:

```
if(hashMap.TryGetValue(item, out int ptr)){

    T myStruct = *ptr; // don't know the right syntax here

    Debug.Log(myStruct.Equals(item)); // should be the same
}
```

I cannot use `IntPtr` because I cannot use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. Unity's compiler does not allow it within its threads.

Comment: Using an int to store a pointer value won't work if you're running in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close but the `int ptr` you get there is still an `int` **address**, not a pointer!

I think what you are looking for would be something like

```
 T myStruct = *((T*)ptr);
```

so first convert the address back to a pointer and then dereference it.

Paranthesis is redundant, just thought it is easier to understand this way. You can also just do

```
T myStruct = *(T*)ptr;
```

or in steps

```
if(hashMap.TryGetValue(item, out int addr))
{
    T* ptr = (T*)addr;
    T myStruct = *ptr;

    Debug.Log(myStruct.Equals(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add in here that I think you *can* use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` if you tick the "allow unsafe code" option in the compilation settings. Go to:

Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Script Compilation > "Allow 'unsafe' Code"

[image]

Comment: I have unsafe on already but you cannot use marhsal in unity's burst compiler.

Comment: If you wouldn't have this then OP wouldn't be allowed to use pointers either in the first place ;)